# Put one-to-many information from joins in subarrays

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, pdo

I have two tables, the first of which looks something like this:

```
customer
----------
id
name
age
sex
```

And another table that looks like this:

```
phone
---------
id
customer_id
number
ext
phone_type
```

If I want to get a customer with all his phone numbers, I do a join and might get back data that looks like this:

```
id  name   age   sex   number     ext  phone_type
---------------------------------------------------
1   Bob    36    M     555-4343   3    office
1   Bob    36    M     555-1111        mobile
2   Sue    23    F     123-4444   42   office
2   Sue    23    F     123-2222        home
2   Sue    23    F     123-1111        mobile
```

Using PHP, I would like to get these rows into a more usable data structure. Instead of having an associative array with 5 rows, I'd like to have an associative array with 2 rows, one for Bob and one for Sue. Then, each row would have a field called "phone" that holds an array with all of the customer's phone numbers in it.

I've looked through all the fetch modes PDO offers and didn't notice anything that would help. The only thing I can think of doing is iterating through every row in the returned dataset and building a whole new array. If I have a large returned dataset, this seems like it could get really inefficient. Is there a PDO fetch method or an efficient way to solve this problem?